# Abstraction layer for different storage

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, abstraction

I need to build an abstraction layer for storage our apps. Data would be saved in either dynamoDB, S3 , Mongo or Mysql(this can change). Our app would receive GET and POST request. And app would reach out to the abstraction layer and this layer should decide what is the current data storage being used and should save or get data from the current storage. We should have the flexibility to change the storage at any point of time with minimal changes in the code. What is the best way to design this Abstraction layer?

Comment: I'd say the best answer is... don't.  In most cases, one of these technoligies is more appropriate than the others, and an abstraction layer covering all of them will tend to prevent you from optimal usage of any of them.  Use the right technology for the task.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical Strategy and Factory design pattern.

You will have abstract `Storage` and anything you want to implement will be following the same contract(eg. `MongoDBStorage`, `CassandraStorage`).

I would actually create `NoSQLStorage` and `RelationalStorage` as separate abstractions but under same `Storage` because their datastructure might be different, as One to Many tables in Relational most of the time become only one Table/Collection in NoSQL. That might add very undesirable and unwanted complexity.

Again, S3 is different storage than Relational or NonRelational, and I would hesitate to solve all kind of problems with one knife. (*But for simplicity I'm assuming they accept similar inputs.*)

And internally inside each strategy you will have to wrap the actual storage API and simply transform your input to the one that actual storage API supports. For example, you will have to translate `StorageRecord` to `DBObject` for MongoDB.

The design would very roughly look something like below, I'm using scala lang for the design, you definitely can use any OO lang.

**Storage abstraction which will be exposed to the client**

```
trait Storage {
  def insert(record: StorageRecord): Boolean
  def query(query: Query): List[StorageRecord]
  def update(updateCondition: Query, updateQuery: Query)
  def delete(deleteCondition: Query)
}

trait RelationalStorage extends Storage

trait StorageRecord
trait Query

trait NoSQLStorage extends Storage
```

**Implementations**

```
class MongoDBStorage extends NoSQLStorage {
  override def insert(record: StorageRecord): Boolean = ???

  override def query(query: Query): List[StorageRecord] = ???

  override def update(updateCondition: Query, updateQuery: Query): Unit = ???

  override def delete(deleteCondition: Query): Unit = ???
}

class DynamoDBStorage extends NoSQLStorage {
  override def insert(record: StorageRecord): Boolean = ???

  override def query(query: Query): List[StorageRecord] = ???

  override def update(updateCondition: Query, updateQuery: Query): Unit = ???

  override def delete(deleteCondition: Query): Unit = ???
}
```

StorageFactory which the client will call to get the right `Storage`.

```
class NoSQLStorageFactory {

  def getStorage(config: String): Storage = {
    config match {
      case "MongoDB" => new MongoDBStorage
      case "DynamoDB" => new DynamoDBStorage
      case _ => throw new Exception("Storage not configured")
    }
  }
}
```

Client code would look like below, you can have the storage server, database name, storage driver as configurable properties that way you simply can change the configuration to make things working.

```
val storage = applicationConfig.get("storage.driver")
val storage = new NoSQLStorageFactory().getStorage(storage)
storage.insert(instanceOfYourStorageRecord)
```